# Automatically deploy a new laravel installation with custom domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, autodeploy

This is not really a specific question about my code, but I would like to ask you guys to think with me.

I am working on a SaaS-application that I will provide to a few customers. The customers will be able to deploy their own SaaS-application on our server. I want the following workflow:

- The customer provide their wanted subdomain and will point a cname to our server
- Optional: the customer provides the credentials for the admin user for the application
- When the user has provided their subdomain, and in addition their wanted login, a new laravel application will be installed fromout a git. I also want a nginx file to be created, so their cname will be pointed to the new directory of the application.

I was looking at laravel multi-tenancy but this would require a lot of recoding of the application. But if it is not possible on any other way, I would do that if needed.

I hope you guys understand my question a bit. It is hard for me to explain it, because most of it is in my head.

I hope you guys have some answers.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Serge

Comment: Well - what have you already tried to achieve this? What plattform should all of this happen on? In general this sounds like you simply need a deploy script that does exactly the steps you described. Even though your application might require recoding when using multitenancy, it's probably worth it. You will need to update every instance if you do a change instead of a single instance. You will need to undo migrations on all instances if you did a mistake. Even with scripts it can be tricky. What happens if one instances fails, but all others succeed? You probably don't want to rollback all...

Comment: Hey @Frnak! I have indeed chosen the path to make the application multi-tenant. A lot easier when updating the application. Thank you a lot for this answer. Appreciate it.